# Angular - Load custom template using dynamic path with fallback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to replace the following code in my **routes**:

```
angular.module('app').config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
    .state 'statistics',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
        templateUrl: '/app/statistics.html'
```

By something like this:

```
angular.module('app').config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
    .state 'statistics',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
        templateUrl: Something.resolveTemplatePath('/app/statistics.html')
```

My goal is to add a *prefix* based on some configuration, but I need to know if the path with the prefix actually exists.

I need to call this in my routes, so I probably need to put this function is a Provider, right? And I don't really know how to check if the template exists or not. I believe Angular makes an AJAX call to load the template and I saw that I could check if the file is found or not, but I'm not sure what the best solution is.

Because if the file with prefix doesn't exist, then I must load the file without prefix (fallback).

What is the best way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where would this configuration for the prefix exist? Inside your Angular code or would it be part of a build tool like Gulp/Grunt?

Assuming that this 'prefix' would be an Angular constant by the name `TEMPLATE_PREFIX`, you could use a combination of `$templateCache` and the `templateProvider` given by ui-router to do

```
templateProvider: Something.resolveTemplatePath('/app/statistics.html')
```

And the definition of `Something` as a service as -

```
angular.module('app').service('Something', function($templateCache, TEMPLATE_PREFIX) {
  this.resolveTemplatePath = function(templateURL) {
    return $templateCache.get(TEMPLATE_PREFIX + templateURL) || $templateCache.get(templateURL);
  }
});
```

There's a great grunt build task for populating `$templateCache` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates

Comment: I did something similar since the time of posting. Thanks for your feedback! But I got stuck because the `$templateCache` isn't populated when I call it from my route. I need to populate it before to call the routing part of the app.

Comment: Thats the reason I recommended using a javascript build task that'll take your html files and make a javascript file for putting them into the templatecache.  Take a look at the grunt module that I've mentioned.